# Remove top levels of stacktrace from Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a log4net implementation that is kept in a class and that class is accessed from a static `ExceptionHandler` class (to avoid changing a bunch of usages, as this is a legacy codebase). So, when exceptions are logged, they look like this:

```
System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback > 
InternalMethod1 > 
InternalMethod2 > 
ExceptionHandler.HandleException > 
Logger.Log
```

I really don't want these last two to be present in the call stack because they obfuscate where the error was actually logged from, which is in `InternalMethod2`. However, the only way I see of doing this is to expose the actual logger to `InternalMethod2` and I don't want to do that either.

Is there a way I can curate my stacktrace so that it displays the situation accurately?

My Logger Class:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(Exception ex, string message)
    {
        log4net.LogManager.Get("MyLog").Error(ex, message);
    }
}
```

My ExceptionHandler class:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly static Logger MyLogger = new Logger();

    HandleException(Exception ex, string message)
    {
        MyLogger.Log(ex, message);
    }
}
```

My call in `InternalMethod2`:

```
void InternalMethod2()
{
    // do some stuff
    try
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleException(e, "An error occurred");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code in ExceptionHandler, in Logger.Log and a sample of InternalMethod2?

Comment: @A.Chiesa I have done so. As you can see, the call stack will show the exception being "thrown" in my logger class. Additionally, the `%location` variable will show the location of my logger class

Comment: Is the code complete or simplified? There is nothing in your code that could possibly change the stacktrace of the exception. Look for `throw e;` calls instead of `throw;`.

Comment: @A.Chiesa The code is simplified but all `throw` statements occur within the method or within methods called by the method. I had found several `throw e;` statements when I was doing the conversion and I changed those but there are none that occur within `Logger.Log`. Furthermore, the stack trace that I'm talking about is a `log4net` variable so I'm unsure as to how that's being set

Comment: You are using the wrong pattern: the %exception token formats the exception text *including* the stacktrace of the exception. Instead, you are using the %stacktrace token, which, as per documentation (https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm) refers to the stacktrace of the log call. Personally, I prefer to pre format the exception by myself, unwrapping eventual inner exceptions, logging both message and stacktrace for every exception in the pack.

Comment: @A.Chiesa In that case, please post that as your answer and I will accept it as it solves the problem I'm currently having. However, that makes me wonder what the utility of `stacktrace` is and how I could go about removing the top levels from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm).
The `%stacktrace` token inserts the stacktrace referring to the method outputting the log. This is useful when using a different pattern than yours, i.e. inserting a `ILog` in each class. Something like this:

```
private static log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ThisClass));
```

When outputting the exception details you can use the `%exception` token.

However, I use a slightly different approach: I pre-format the exception details using an extension method of the `ILog` interface.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs an exception as an error in the provided logger,
    /// formatting message and stacktrace.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public static void ErrorFromException(this ILog logger, Exception e)
    {
        ErrorFromException(logger, null, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs an exception as an error in the provided logger,
    /// formatting message and stacktrace.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="prefix"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public static void ErrorFromException(this ILog logger, string prefix, Exception e)
    {
        if (logger == null) return;

        if (e == null)
        {
            logger.Error(
                "LogExtension.ErrorFromException: A null exception was formatted. Probably there is a bug in the logging call.");
            return;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder(400);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
            sb.AppendLine(prefix);

        sb.AppendLine("Caught exception (" + e.GetType().Name + "): " + e.Message);
        sb.AppendLine(e.StackTrace);

        var innerEx = e;

        while (innerEx.InnerException != null)
        {
            innerEx = innerEx.InnerException;
            sb.AppendLine("Inner exception (" + innerEx.GetType().Name + "): " + innerEx.Message);
            sb.AppendLine(innerEx.StackTrace);
        }

        sb.AppendLine();
        logger.Error(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Hope it helps.